# Acumatica Web API popup Note (Enter Record Note)

Tags: popup, record, acumatica

I saw that once the Document is Closed/canceled/hold, there is no way to change any data field but the "Notes". Then Document notes is the way to save some critical information we need to track about the document.

So I think to create a new Screen to manage the "Record notes" using the guid as parameter.

Before go any further, is there a simple way to update the Notes if I know the guid, without using the SO screen?

Comment: Why is it that you do not want to use the SO screen?

Comment: The button "save" is disable message happens. Do you have an example on how to modifiy a closed order "note"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom screen which displays the notes related to an object, in your case an SO. You will need a selector to select the order number, and then using said order number, you can link it to its notes. Here is an example view to get the note you will edit:

```
    public PXSelectJoin<Note, InnerJoinSingleTable<SOOrder, On<SOOrder.noteID, 
Equal<Note.noteID>>>, Where<SOOrder.orderNbr, Equal<Current<SOOrder.orderNbr>>>> SONote;
```